# c# windows form ( i need to print form crystal report 1 user only )

Tags: c#, ms-access

i am trying to print from crystal report but i am getting an error. here is pic of what i want to do [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGLKv.png) . the text box is for the users ID. when i type the id then press the button i want to print only that user information.
this is my code

```
if (conect.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            conect.Open();
        }

        string cs = "select * from Sign_Up where ID='"+textBox1.Text+"'";
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(cs, conect);
        OleDbDataAdapter adap = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        adap.Fill(ds, "Sign_Up");

        CrystalReport1 crs1 = new CrystalReport1();
        crs1.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["Sign_Up"]);
        crs1.SetDataSource(ds);
        crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crs1;
        conect.Close();
        crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```

and this is my error

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

at this code `adap.Fill(ds, "Sign_Up");`

anyone have any suggestions ?

Comment: You are forcing ID - which sounds like a number - to be passed as text.  Always use SQL Parameters.  Always.

Comment: @MakeStackOverflowGoodAgain actually i see a lot of people talk about parameters but i don' know how to use it that's why i am trying this this my collage project and this is the last part of it

Comment: Please read [Why do we prefer using parameters in SQL statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/)?

Comment: @DourHighArch i still didnt get parameters 
like in this line 
SqlCommand query =  new SqlCommand("SELECT empSalary FROM employee 
                                    WHERE salary = @sal;"); 
what @ sal mean ? is it the data base filed name or its just a random name :/ ?

Comment: Don't use apostrophe delimiters for number type field criteria, they are for text fields.

Comment: @June7 what should i use ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use apostrophe delimiters for number type field criteria, they are for text fields. This is causing 'data type mismatch' error.

`string cs = "select * from Sign_Up where ID=" + textBox1.Text;`

Use of parameters would be vital if project has any sort of public accessibility (web, remote user). The `sal` would be a declared parameter variable and `@` signifies use of parameter in SQL statement.